# Is it possible to do data analysis in Open Office Calc?

Tags: software, excel, calc

I have recently come across the mircosoft data analysis tool add-on, and I was wondering if there was something comparable that can be used with OpenOffice?

However, if there is nothing for OpenOffice, is there any other software that can be used in Ubuntu-Linux that can do similar things?

Comment: related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-are-some-valuable-statistical-analysis-open-source-projects

Comment: [This add-on can do t-test, plot histogram and even calculate covariance](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-statistical-analysis-tools-HP005203873.aspx)! Stunning.

Comment: Better use a true data analysis software. The functionalities offered in speadsheets are very limited and often just boil down to exporting the data into a better software such as R or ELKI, then analyzing it, then importing it back into the speadsheet. Doesn't make much sense to me...

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can do statistics in Open Office Calc:

- Here is a list of [statistical functions in LibreOffice Calc](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060100.html?&DbPAR=CALC&System=MAC)
- Possibly out of date suggestions

  - There is an add on called [R and Calc](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/R_and_Calc_Documentation) (page last modified in 2008; ymmv) that allows the user to call R functions from within Open Office.
  - Calc's [data analysis tool](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc/To-Dos/Statistical_Data_Analysis_Tool) is under development. 
    (page last modified in 2008)

However, the spreadsheet interface can get in the way of data analysis, and is often not the appropriate tool for the job.

- If you are primarily interested in data analysis, it is worth checking out the [Deducer](http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.DeducerManual) or [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.org/) interfaces to R.
- [Ggobi](http://www.ggobi.org) is a good tool for data visualization. (Update: also pre-2010)

Answer (score 2):

Gnumeric

http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/

will do various statistical analyses. After installation they are found under Statistics in the top (File, Edit, etc.) menu.

Answer (score 1):

First post here!

I've used this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ooomacros/files/OOo%20Statistics/

to do stats in openoffice (and recommended it to others as well).

I usually use R but sometimes a quick look is all you need.

best

i

Comment: I managed to install this for OO, my problem is that I am trying to find the error in the slope. I know that it can be done on excel, but I am not sure how it can be done in open office. I should have probably made that clear.

Comment: @picakhu, the best way to do that in Oo would be to use the arithmetic functions to solve the equation (and perhaps you could ask another question if you have trouble with that)

Answer (score 0):

Sofastats looks really well done, and it can import from OpenOffice files.

http://www.sofastatistics.com/